# Android. How can I create a platform indepedant text file?

Tags: android, ascii

I am programming an Android app that creates multi line txt files. I want these files to be readable in both Android and Windows. My problem is with line separators. 
I know I can `\n` to make an android readable file, or `\r\n` for a file to be readable in windows. I know also I can use `System.getProperty("line.separator")`, that since my program runs in android it adds an Android line separator. 
Is there a way to create text files that are correctly readable in both windows and android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, Windows uses `\r\n` as its line separator, whereas UNIX uses only `\n`. There is no (standard) workaround for this.